# What are "marker for NULL pointers" in binary tree?

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree, nodes, implementation

I was going through [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-bst-from-given-preorder-traversal-set-2/) and [this](http://www.sanfoundry.com/csharp-program-binary-search-tree-linked-list/) post about [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) implementation.

I saw that a binary search tree is represented as *(for example)*:

[image: BST]

> 1 5 7 10 40 50

I was trying to learn about the serialization or de-serialization of the same [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-binary-tree/). The blog post is making me crazy with those **-1**s which they're calling **markers for NULL pointers**. And they're representing the tree as:

[image: BST with -1s]

> 20 8 4 -1 -1 12 10 -1 -1 14 -1 -1 -1

**Confusion**

What are those **-1**s?

My final goal is to store and read a binary search tree to some kind of file using C# but this confusion is keeping me off.

Comment: This solution will work if all valid node values are cardinal (>= 0). **-1** means *no value* in this case. You can use any in-valid value instead of it.

Comment: I'm assuming that the tree can only store non-negative integers? Then you can't represent an empty branch with a zero (which is the usual value for `NULL`) and need some other value that can't be in the tree.

Comment: the -1 is just telling the algoruthm that there is no more values after that number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These `-1` stand for places where there is no more childs.

For your example

```
     20
    /
   8__
  /   \
4      12
       /\
     10  14
```

You can imagine adding additional `-1` (you can use any value that can not occur in the tree itself) to places where nodes have no children:

```
       20
      /   \
     8__   -1
    /   \
  4      12
 /\      /\
-1 -1   10  14
        /\   /\
      -1 -1 -1 -1
```

And now if you go through your tree in "root, then left subtree, then right subtree" order, you will get the following string:

```
20 8 4 -1 -1 12 10 -1 -1 14 -1 -1 -1
```

Which is exactly what you have. So this is a way to represent the tree in an array form. At the same time, it is easy to reconstruct the tree from that form. Knowing that these `-1`s are special in a sense that they have no more children, you can reconstruct the tree from such an array without any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I'm wondering, how the heck you managed to draw those trees? Is it some **markdown** rule we don't know?

Comment: @xameeramir, just [prepend four spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for something that you want to be formatted as code.

Answer (score 2):

Not all nodes have two children. Obviously, because the tree would be infinite otherwise. At runtime/in memory, a missing node is represented by a `nullptr`, on disk by `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of these `-1`'s was explained in other answers, let me present the code of reading and writing a tree:

```
class Tree
{
public:
  int value;
  Tree* left;
  Tree* right;

  Tree(int i_value, Tree* i_left, Tree* i_right)
    : value(i_value), left(i_left), right(i_right)
  {}
  Tree(const Tree&) = delete;

  static const int NO_TREE = -1;

  template<typename Iterator>
  static Tree* Create(Iterator& i_iterator)
  {
    if (*i_iterator == NO_TREE)
    {
      i_iterator++;
      return nullptr;
    }
    int value = *(i_iterator++);
    Tree* left = Create(i_iterator);
    Tree* right = Create(i_iterator);
    return new Tree(value, left, right);
  }

  template<typename Iterator>
  static void Write(Tree* i_tree, Iterator& i_iterator)
  {
    if (i_tree == nullptr)
    {
      *(i_iterator++) = NO_TREE;
      return;
    }
    *(i_iterator++) = i_tree->value;
    Write(i_tree->left, i_iterator);
    Write(i_tree->right, i_iterator);
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
vector<int> v = { 20, 8, 4, -1, -1, 12, 10, -1, -1, 14, -1, -1, -1 };
Tree* t = Tree::Create(v.begin());
vector<int> w;
Tree::Write(t, std::back_inserter(w));
```

Comment: I was trying to do this in `C#`. Thanks!