# (Manually) serialize and de-serialize a binary search tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, file, serialization, binary-search-tree

I have [implemented binary search tree in C#](https://github.com/xameeramir/CSharp-BinarySearchTree) using [standard approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx).

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/xameeramir/CSharp-BinarySearchTree/blob/master/BinarySearchTree.cs)

I'm not able to figure out how can I do this using [custom approach](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-binary-tree/). **How can this be done using C# manually?**

Comment: Please show the actual data types used for representation of the tree.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? How to serialize/deserialize, or how to implement it?

Comment: What doesn't work for you? BinaryFormatter should be able to handle such a structure w/o any problem. The only potential problem could be the event. There is no need to use markers.

Comment: @xameeramir: so how does this differ from your [previous question with an accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33822501/2404470)?

Comment: @Groo - that question was about NULL pointers which I believe are not there in C#. So I was not sure about pointers thing

Comment: You want to serialize/deserialize manually (w/o using BinaryFormatter)?

Comment: @IvanStoev - yes, I have corrected my question wordings now.

Comment: References in C# are basically pointers, they can be `null`, so you need a way to represent this value. So the C++ serialization will work equally in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a binary data to a file (or stream), you need to put some "marker" (indicator) for null (in contrast with XML where you have a natural "missing" element/attribute). It could be anything, the most natural would be a `bool` representing something similar to `Nullable<T>.HasValue`, but for `Node` reference, like this

```
class ObjectPersistence
{
    public void StoreBSTToFile(BST bst, string TreeStoreFile)
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(TreeStoreFile)))
            WriteNode(writer, bst.root);
    }
    public BST ReadBSTFromFile(string TreeStoreFile)
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(TreeStoreFile)))
            return new BST { root = ReadNode(reader) };
    }
    private static void WriteNode(BinaryWriter output, Node node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            output.Write(false);
        else
        {
            output.Write(true);
            output.Write(node.key);
            WriteNode(output, node.leftc);
            WriteNode(output, node.rightc);
        }
    }
    private static Node ReadNode(BinaryReader input)
    {
        if (!input.ReadBoolean()) return null;
        var node = new Node();
        node.key = input.ReadInt32();
        node.leftc = ReadNode(input);
        node.rightc = ReadNode(input);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you wouldn't use some of standard (de)serialization techniques (`BinaryFormatter`, `XmlSerializer`, data contracts, protocol buffers)?

But if you really want to use the approach given in the link, the point of the article can be summarized into:

> A simple solution is to store **both** Inorder and Preorder traversals. This solution requires requires space **twice the size** of Binary Tree.

When represented this way, you have to use a "dummy" value for empty nodes. And since the author of [the linked article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialize-deserialize-binary-tree/) used the tree to store *integers*, (s)he chose to use the "special" `-1` value for empty nodes.

But if you are *not* storing the tree this way internally (I presume you are using a linked list), then there is not point in adding these dummy values. If you are storing plain C# objects, than a `null` value clearly describes an empty node.

If your intention is to port the C++ to C# completely, then the serialization method would look like this:

```
// This function stores a tree in a file pointed by fp
void Serialize(Node root, StreamWriter writer)
{
    // If current node is NULL, store marker
    if (root == null)
    {
        writer.Write("{0} ", MARKER);
        return;
    }

    // Else, store current node and recur for its children
    writer.Write("{0} ", root.key);
    Serialize(root.leftc, writer);
    Serialize(root.rightc, writer);
}
```

But this is very specific to your tree, as it only works for simple keys (like integers in your case), and it's not very space/speed efficient.

Comment: @xameeramir: but note that the author of your article only used the tree for storing integers. In a general case, the value of your node will be an object (i.e. a reference in C#, or a pointer in C++), and `null` is a perfectly reasonable value for an empty node.

Comment: @xameeramir: ok, I read the article and the author wasn't actually using an array to store the tree, but instead storing both inorder and preorder traversals separately. I've updated my answer.